# Refactor Switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement - it takes responses I get from Web Service and maps them to fields at my object level and then persists the updates to the DB.

```
foreach (var webServiceResponse in response.Values)
{
    switch (webServiceResponse.Name)
    {
        case Constants.A:
          myObject.A = (double) webServiceResponse.Value;
          break;
        case Constants.B:
          myObject.B = (double) webServiceResponse.Value;
          break;
        case Constants.C:
          myObject.C = (double) webServiceResponse.Value;
          break;
          //numerous more same pattern removed for readability
     }
}
```

Is there a better pattern I could use to get rid of the switch statement and just loop over all the responses and map them to the fields on my object?  Perhaps a Dictionary would be the best approach - if anyone has a code sample or link to something similar done with a Dictionary?

Comment: Are you able to control the response from the web service?  If so, you may want to consider XML serialization or JSON serialization instead of doing manual name / value mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to do it, assuming Constants.whatever truly matches the name of the property on `myObject`.

```
foreach (var webServiceRespone in response.Values)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(webServiceResponse.Name);
    if (propInfo != null)
        propInfo.SetValue(myObject, webServiceResponse.Value);
}
```

Comment: They dont Fully match - e.g of the constant - public const string A= "VALUEA"; which on myObject I have double ValueA; - I suppose I could easily rename the fields on myObject so they match

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do to loop over all the responses and map them to the fields on my object using dictionary and reflection.

Here is the dictionary with the definition for the fields

```
   private static Dictionary<string, string> GetAttributeNames()
   {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>()
         {
            { "Name1", "Name - 1" },   
            { "Name2", "Name - 2" }, 
            { "Name3", "Name - 3" }
        };
        return dic;
   }
```

Loop over and map them to fields of the object

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> row in GetAttributeNames())
{
      myClass myobj = new myClass
      {
          FieldName = row.Value,
          FieldValue = PropertyHasValue(response.Values, row.Key),
      };
}
```

And the reflection method

```
   // using reflection to get the object's property value
    public static String PropertyHasValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                if (prop != null)
                {
                    string sVal = String.Empty;
                    object val = prop.GetValue(obj, null);

                    if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(System.DateTime?))
                        sVal = Convert.ToString(val);
                    else // format the date to contain only the date portion of it
                        sVal = Convert.ToDateTime(val).Date.ToString("d"); ;

                    if (sVal != null)
                    {
                        return sVal;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I'm sure you can customize it to you needs.